# How can I change width of a custom widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a table to display tabular data in tkinter. I want the table to to cover the whole screen width and the problem is, the `width` argument doesn't do anything.

```
class Cell(Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self._parent = parent
        self.bind("<Button-1>", parent.select)
        self.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.do_sth)
    
    def do_sth(self, event):
        print("Double Click")


class Row(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, data, col_width=10, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self._labels = {}
        self.cols = {}
        self.col_width = col_width
        self.selected = False
        for i_cols, (col, col_data) in enumerate(data.items()):
            self.cols.update({col:StringVar()})
            self.cols[col].set(f'{col_data}')
            l = Cell(self, textvariable=self.cols[col], width=self.col_width, background="#ffffff")
            l.grid(row=0, column=i_cols)
            self._labels.update({col:l})

        ttk.Separator(self).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=len(self.cols))

    def select(self, event):
        self.master.deselect_all_rows()
        self.select = True
        for l in self._labels.values():
            l.configure(background="blue", foreground="white")
    
    def deselect(self):
        self.select = False
        for l in self._labels.values():
            l.configure(background="#ffffff", foreground="black")

    def __str__(self):
        str_out = '{'
        for c, l in self._labels.items():
            str_out += f'{c}:{l.cget("text")}, '
        str_out = str_out[:-2]
        str_out += '}'
        return str_out 


class Table(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, table_name, table_cols, col_width=10, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, background="#000000", *args, **kwargs)
        self.name = table_name
        self.cols = table_cols
        self.rows = []
        self._count_row = 0
        self._count_col = len(table_cols)
        self.col_width = col_width
        for i, col_name in enumerate(self.cols):
            Label(self, text=col_name, width=self.col_width, background="#aaaaaa").grid(row=0, column=i)
    
    def add_row(self, data):
        r = Row(self, data, col_width=self.col_width)
        self._count_row += 1
        r.grid(row=self._count_row, column=0, columnspan=self._count_col)
        self.rows.append(r)

    def deselect_all_rows(self):
        for r in self.rows:
            r.deselect()



class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.rows=[]
        self.cols = [
            'نام مشتری',
            'تاریخ',
            'نام سفارش',
            'فلان',
            'بیسار',
            'فلان بیسار'
        ]
        self.root = root
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, background="#ffffff", borderwidth=0)
        self.frame = Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        # self.scrolly = Scrollbar(self.root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        # self.scrollx = Scrollbar(self.root, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        # self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrolly.set)#, xscrollcommand=self.scrollx.set)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", tags="self.frame")
        # self.scrolly.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        # self.scrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self._size = (root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight())


        t = Table(self.frame, 'my_table', table_cols=self.cols, width=1920)
        
        for i in range(30):
            data = {}
            for c in self.cols: 
                data.update({c:f'{i}-{c}'})
            
            t.add_row(data)
        
        t.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=len(self.cols))

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    def callback(self, sv, column, row):
        print("Column: "+str(column)+", Row: "+str(row)+" = "+sv.get())
    def onClick(self, event):
        print("Hi")

root = Tk()
print(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight())
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

and this is the result in a 1920x1080 display:
[The width argument is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvY6q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just update this line

```
t = Table(self.frame, "my_table", table_cols=self.cols, width=1920, col_width=30)
```

Your table canvas width is changed when you used `width=1920`, but the contents are still limited by `col_width=10`. Take note that `col_width` uses a different unit - number of characters, not pixels.

Final code example:

```py
class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.rows = []
        self.cols = ["نام مشتری", "تاریخ", "نام سفارش", "فلان", "بیسار", "فلان بیسار"]
        self.root = root
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, background="#ffffff", borderwidth=0)
        self.frame = Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.canvas.create_window(
            (4, 4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", tags="self.frame"
        )
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self._size = (root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight())

        t = Table(self.frame, "my_table", table_cols=self.cols, width=1920, col_width=30)

        for i in range(30):
            data = {}
            for c in self.cols:
                data.update({c: f"{i}-{c}"})

            t.add_row(data)

        t.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=len(self.cols))

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def callback(self, sv, column, row):
        print("Column: " + str(column) + ", Row: " + str(row) + " = " + sv.get())

    def onClick(self, event):
        print("Hi")
```

[image: screenshot of final results]